# The import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring

I have creating a new Spring Project in Eclipse using Maven. I am using Spring Version 5.0.8.RELEASE

When trying to create a Java Configuration Class, I am faced with this error:

> The import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan cannot be resolved

After changing my Spring Version to 5.0.5.RELEASE, everything just miraculously works. What is the problem here? Is there something wrong with the newest version of Spring?

Comment: This is dependency resolution problem. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871437/the-import-org-springframework-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: Purge your local dependencies (assuming you are using Maven) then redownload the dependencies. You probably have a borked jar somewhere in your repository.