# How do I run an existing Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I am trying to get OIDC working with Java Spring Boot. Specifically the example app 
[here](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/simple-web-app).

I am a newbie to this stuff, so can anyone give me brief instructions on how to run that app?

I have it in Eclipse (with STS4) as existing maven project (as per [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871437/the-import-org-springframework-cannot-be-resolved) instructions). When I run it I pick 'Java application' which gives me some examples including version, Licence, roller etc etc. I do not know which, if any, of these is correct, nor how do I pass parameters etc. Any pointers are gratefully received.

Comment: use run as springboot app ,it will do .

Comment: Thanks. I do not see that option.

Comment: The link you gave is not even a Spring Boot application.

Comment: Ah! OK it is Spring and that is not the same as Spring Boot, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think example code is not Spring boot app. (just Spring web app) You can run it via Eclipse / Tomcat.
If you review below link you can see details in section 6;

> Eclipse allows us to embed servers to add web project deployment in the normal workflow without navigating away from the IDE

Check this out: [tomcat-deploy-war](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war)

Answer (score 0):

From the project overview list, pick the Application class. Right-click on it to open the context menu and choose "Run as -> Spring Boot App". Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse Project Explorer, right click the project name -> select "Run As" -> "Maven Build..."
In the goals, enter spring-boot:run
then click Run button.

In STS right click on Project > Run as > Spring Boot App

If you are not getting any option then just run the main method which is in the class SampleSpringBootApplication. Spring Boot will take care of all the rest (starting the embedded tomcat which will host your sample application).

Comment: Thanks. That gave:  No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project.

Comment: @schoon That's because your project is **not** a Spring Boot application

Comment: Exactly @schoon indeed its not an spring boot application...nice catch Eugen

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855864/maven-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-spring-boot-in-the-current-project-and-in-th